# Raising an Event on Button Click

Tags: javascript

I have a button on which I want to raise an event. Is this possible?

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //raise change event
});
```

**I want to raise the change Event of a button on click**

Comment: Hi John, what is your question? To trigger an other event after a button has been clicked check the demos at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

```
function myEvent (){


}

button.addEventListener('click', myEvent);
......
```

and then just call the function you bound to it: `myEvent();`

Comment: I want to call the change Event of a button... on its click

Comment: It sounds like you want to **raise** the change event in the click event handler.